# JSON.parse() unexpected token error

Tags: json, angularjs

I am getting `unexpected token` error when trying to parse this JSON string

```
$scope.feeds = JSON.parse('[{"id":"212216417436_10152811286407437","from":{ "category":"Movie","name":"The Lord of the Rings Trilogy","id":"212216417436"},"story":"The Lord of the Rings Trilogy shared The Hobbit\'s photo.","picture":"https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/1912397_736719376363670_7288336626443028501_n.jpg?oh=a7e83093f61fafa7909ff84263f989e4&oe=54B4481D&__gda__=1420472696_dbd6462629a00e218c849c5ed7b49c44","link":"https://www.facebook.com/TheHobbitMovie/photos/a.291674244201521.63650.160617097307237/736719376363670/?type=1","name":"Timeline Photos","caption":"\"I have the only right.\" \n\nWhat is your favorite Thorin quote from #TheHobbit?","properties":[  {  "name":"By","text":"The Hobbit","href":"https://www.facebook.com/TheHobbitMovie?ref=stream"}],"icon":"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif","actions":[  { "name":"Comment","link":"https://www.facebook.com/212216417436/posts/10152811286407437"},{ "name":"Like","link":"https://www.facebook.com/212216417436/posts/10152811286407437"}],"privacy":{ "value":""},"type":"photo","status_type":"shared_story","object_id":"736719376363670","application":{ "name":"Photos","id":"2305272732"},"created_time":"2014-10-12T21:35:41+0000","updated_time":"2014-10-12T21:37:17+0000"},{  "id":"21785951839_10152794856921840","from":{ "category":"App page","name":"9GAG","id":"21785951839"},"message":"Must NOT let my girlfriend see this!\nhttp://9gag.tv/p/a9OrlY?ref=fbl9\n\nWatch more awesome videos on your phone:\nAndroid ► http://goo.gl/Rbi9FP\niPhone/iPad ► http://goo.gl/NFMm9p","picture":"https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCee84KqIBIdnIX&w=158&h=158&url=http%3A%2F%2Fd1d4324mp0stc8.cloudfront.net%2Fmedia%2Fphoto%2FpPgXmO5QJ_600w_v1.jpg","link":"http://9gag.tv/p/a9OrlY?ref=fbl9","name":"This \"Marry Me\" Lip-Sync Proposal Is So Touching And Amazing | 9GAG.tv","caption":"9gag.tv","description":"This sets the bar pretty high!","icon":"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif","actions":[  { "name":"Comment","link":"https://www.facebook.com/21785951839/posts/10152794856921840"},{ "name":"Like","link":"https://www.facebook.com/21785951839/posts/10152794856921840"}],"privacy":{ "value":""},"type":"link","status_type":"shared_story","created_time":"2014-10-12T21:15:00+0000","updated_time":"2014-10-12T21:15:46+0000","shares":{  "count":160}}]');
```

Expanded string object:

```
{
   "id":"212216417436_10152811286407437",
   "from":{
      "category":"Movie",
      "name":"The Lord of the Rings Trilogy",
      "id":"212216417436"
   },
   "story":"The Lord of the Rings Trilogy shared The Hobbit\'s photo.",
   "picture":"https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/v/t1.0-9/s130x130/1912397_736719376363670_7288336626443028501_n.jpg?oh=a7e83093f61fafa7909ff84263f989e4&oe=54B4481D&__gda__=1420472696_dbd6462629a00e218c849c5ed7b49c44",
   "link":"https://www.facebook.com/TheHobbitMovie/photos/a.291674244201521.63650.160617097307237/736719376363670/?type=1",
   "name":"Timeline Photos",
   "caption":"\"I have the only right.\" \n\nWhat is your favorite Thorin quote from #TheHobbit?",
   "properties":[
      {
         "name":"By",
         "text":"The Hobbit",
         "href":"https://www.facebook.com/TheHobbitMovie?ref=stream"
      }
   ],
   "icon":"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
   "actions":[
      {
         "name":"Comment",
         "link":"https://www.facebook.com/212216417436/posts/10152811286407437"
      },
      {
         "name":"Like",
         "link":"https://www.facebook.com/212216417436/posts/10152811286407437"
      }
   ],
   "privacy":{
      "value":""
   },
   "type":"photo",
   "status_type":"shared_story",
   "object_id":"736719376363670",
   "application":{
      "name":"Photos",
      "id":"2305272732"
   },
   "created_time":"2014-10-12T21:35:41+0000",
   "updated_time":"2014-10-12T21:37:17+0000"
},
{
   "id":"21785951839_10152794856921840",
   "from":{
      "category":"App page",
      "name":"9GAG",
      "id":"21785951839"
   },
   "message":"Must NOT let my girlfriend see this!\nhttp://9gag.tv/p/a9OrlY?ref=fbl9\n\nWatch more awesome videos on your phone:\nAndroid ► http://goo.gl/Rbi9FP\niPhone/iPad ► http://goo.gl/NFMm9p",
   "picture":"https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCee84KqIBIdnIX&w=158&h=158&url=http%3A%2F%2Fd1d4324mp0stc8.cloudfront.net%2Fmedia%2Fphoto%2FpPgXmO5QJ_600w_v1.jpg",
   "link":"http://9gag.tv/p/a9OrlY?ref=fbl9",
   "name":"This \"Marry Me\" Lip-Sync Proposal Is So Touching And Amazing | 9GAG.tv",
   "caption":"9gag.tv",
   "description":"This sets the bar pretty high!",
   "icon":"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif",
   "actions":[
      {
         "name":"Comment",
         "link":"https://www.facebook.com/21785951839/posts/10152794856921840"
      },
      {
         "name":"Like",
         "link":"https://www.facebook.com/21785951839/posts/10152794856921840"
      }
   ],
   "privacy":{
      "value":""
   },
   "type":"link",
   "status_type":"shared_story",
   "created_time":"2014-10-12T21:15:00+0000",
   "updated_time":"2014-10-12T21:15:46+0000",
   "shares":{
      "count":160
   }
}
```

Comment: That error is caused by trying to parse invalid JSON, and what you've posted is invalid json according to [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: oh it is valid JSON. JsonLint said so.

Comment: Nope, thats because you probably posted it as a string, but actually you should post the array.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

verify your json string. If it is ok try this:

```
var jsonStr="your json string";
var json=JSON.stringify(jsonStr);
json=JSON.parse(json)
```

Comment: That converts it from a string of JSON into a string of a string of JSON and then back to a string of JSON. That won't successfully parse JSON and is equivalent to `var json="your json string";`

Comment: that is not true. stringify just converts the input data to  JSON text and stores that JSON text in a string.

Answer (score 2):

When you're typing a string in javascript, the \ is treated as escaping character, while you need it in your json to actually be a \ and not escaping character.

You need to change the `\"` to `\\"` and `\n` to `\\n`, while keeping the `\'` because it is already an escaping character and it should be parsed okay

Comment: The double-slashes fixed my issue.  It's frustrating but I guess it makes sense.  You couldn't have `\"` be an escaped character but not consider `\r` to be one.