# How to fix a json format error on javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I am using `JSON.parse` to parse a json string. It works fine for standard json format string but I doesn't work for some string like below:

```
'{"filter":{"email":/net/}, 
  "rejected":"[/net/,/net/]"
 }'
```

the problem on this string is that it missing double quote on `/net/` which makes `JSON.parse` failed. Is there a way to parse this string into json object? Or is there a library to add a double quote on the missing part of this string? I tried a few regex patterns to make up this string but can't find a good solution.

Comment: What is making such `string` ?

Comment: The best fix would be to fix whatever generates these strings.

Comment: Parse after stringiFy check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26334964/json-parse-unexpected-token-error.It is working for me after stringify.

Comment: @Rayon `mongo shell` returns such string